# How to write a matcher that is not equal to specific enum value?

Tags: java, mockito, matcher

As in the question, there's any way I can do it? Below code, which work for String doesn't work. I want any other value than, for example: `SomeEnum.FIRST`

```
when(mock.method(any())).thenReturn(not(eq(SomeEnum.FIRST)));
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve what you want.  You would have to write a function that randomizes on the remaining available types.  I don't see why you would want that though.  Just select one of the remaining values.  You specify what the mock should return when `method(any())` is called.

Comment: `ArgumentMatchters` are not supposed to be used as a parameter for the `thenReturn` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
when(mock.method(any())).thenReturn(SomeEnum.SECOND);
```

Comment: But I want to check any other values also, or I don't need if I think only about 'the other than SomeEnum.FIRST'?

Comment: What do you mean by *'check other values also'*? Please share more context about when and how this mock is used.

Comment: `if(value.equals(SomeEnum.FIRST) {...} else {...}`
SomeEnum has +10 values. I want to use this mock to step into "else" section, and I want to include any other values than SomeEnum.FIRST. I need to do this?